# Trying to figure out the Brand/Make of this bicycle?

Tags: road-bike, frames, steel, identify-this-bike

Got this from a friend hand-me-down style.
Got some work to do on it to make her roadworthy.

But it's been painted, and I can't see a logo or name on it anywhere.
Steel Metal Frame. That's about all I know.

Any ideas? [image]

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty generic to me. You can see if theres a serial number at the headtube or bottom bracket or dropouts, but the paint may have filled it over if there was one.

Comment: Yeah, pretty generic.  There don't appear to be lugs for cables, suggesting it's not a fixie conversion from a geared bike.  (One would assume it has a "coaster" brake rear hub?)  And the dropouts and single-piece bottom bracket suggest fairly low quality.  Department store bike.

Answer (score 1):

Looks a lot like an old Free Spirit road. Note the fork crown, the weld quality around the head tube, the attachment of the rear dropouts and the single-piece bottom bracket.